# increment character using int in a for loop

Tags: java, while-loop, char, int, increment

Trying to increment a character in a 'while loop'.  However I need to increment (starting with 'A') using an int variable.

```
int userNum = 3;
char userLetter = 0;

userLetter = 'A';
while (userLetter <= userNum) {
    System.out.print( userLetter+ " " );
    userLetter++
}
```

Im trying to find the result: A B C

Thank you

Comment: The ASCII value of 'A' is 65, so your loop won't be executed even once.

Comment: Your loop condition is wrong. `'A' <= 3` is false, so the loop is never run.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this simple code to increment.

```
   public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int count=1;
        int userNum = 3;
        char userLetter = 0;

        userLetter = 'A';
        while (count <= userNum) {
            System.out.print( (char)(userLetter+count));
            count++;
        }
             }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this code yourself? It won't do the job.

Comment: I like how you add an extra line to increment `count` when `count` is available to increment in two other places that lines are already defined

Comment: Just copy the code after public static void main it will work

Comment: You can see it running on url i provided

Comment: Sorry bout that.  I see it now. Thanks